# How to correctly handle a confirmation event?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am trying to create frame with 2 input areas (for login and password) and confirmation button (after this button is pressed - code will read areas values). But I don't know how to do it inside class `App` without using some global function.

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame_credentials = Frame(master, width=100, height=200)
        frame_credentials.pack()

        self.label_login = Label(frame_credentials, text='login')
        self.text_login = Entry(frame_credentials, width=15)
        self.label_pass = Label(frame_credentials, text='password')
        self.text_pass = Entry(frame_credentials, show="*", width=15)
        self.button_ok = Button(frame_credentials, text="Login")

        self.label_login.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.text_login.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.label_pass.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.text_pass.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.button_ok.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=4)
        self.button_ok.bind("<Button-1>", enter_in)

    def enter_in(self):
        print self.text_login, self.text_pass

root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. Your sample code is not using any global function.

Comment: Than you run this code you get error - "global name 'enter_in' is not defined". If I will create function "enter_in" outside class App - it will work. But how can it be used inside class App?

Comment: That's because it should be `self.button_ok.bind("<Button-1>", self.enter_in)`. You defined a *method* not a global function. In python you do *not* have "implicit self", you must always refer to `self` to access instance attributes or methods.

Comment: I rewrote it and now have this error - "TypeError: enter_in() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

Comment: I'm not a Tkinter user. Maybe the `'<Button-1>'` signal has an argument and thus you should define `enter_in` as `def enter_in(self, arg):`

Comment: '<Button-1>' determine when this button should triggered (left mouse click, right mouse click etc.). I don't think that will change anything. But I will check it and write about results.

Comment: Bakuriu Thank You Very Much :)
I found how-to do it:
         self.button_ok.bind("<Button-1>", self.enter_in)

    def enter_in(self,event):
        s = self.text_login.get()
        x = self.text_pass.get()
        print x,s

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind to `<Button-1>`; instead, use the `command` attribute and give it the name of a method in your object. For example:

```
class App:
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self.button_ok = Button(..., command=self.enter_in)
        ...
    def enter_in(self):
        <put your login logic here>
```